# How Can I Detemine What a MySQL IF() Condition Did on UPDATE Without Re-SELECTING the Table

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have the following MySQL Statement in place:

```
mysql_query('
    UPDATE states
    SET
        '.$_REQUEST['name'].' = '.$_REQUEST['name'].' + 1,
        limitReached = IF('.$_REQUEST['name'].' = "30", "High", IF('.$_REQUEST['name'].' = "15", "Low", NULL))
    WHERE region = "' . $_REQUEST['region'] . '"
    LIMIT 1
');
```

I wish to take certain actions depending on what happens to the limitReached column. But I prefer to not re-read the table with a subsequent query select.

Is it possible to have MySQL report what it did in my IF() condition?

[It's sort of like the rows affected result, but more so, for a column affected situation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge you cannot.

What you could do is have the IF done in PHP (if it's an option), then you'll know what was the result of IF.

Comment: Thanks Alexandru. But I can't do it that way (I know the sql above is a bit tough to follow) but the IF() is happening by and within MySQL and PHP can't come into play at that time.

Comment: What I am toying with now is if I prepend the query select with a "$result = " I am trying to dump the "$result" to see what MySQL gives me on an update query.

Comment: I see. Well, it looks like you'll have to do another select. As you said the only thing you can get back is the number of affected rows. Unless somebody knows something I don't.

Comment: From http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php "For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error. " - Nothing more.

Comment: Yea, looks like I have no choice.

Comment: I ended up implementing a subsequent query statement. Thanks Alexandru.